# Checking if conditions hold in boolean list

Tags: python, string, list, boolean

I'm trying to run some function if a list of booleans is true.
My list consists of boolean functions.

```
list = [file.endswith('05',21,22), file.endswith('11',21,22),
       file.endswith('17',21,22), file.endswith('21',21,22),
       file.endswith('23',21,22)]

if any(True in list) == True:           
    # do something
```

Currently, the if clause gives me an error

```
  if any(True in list) == True:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: Don't shadow the builtin `list`.

Answer (score 4):

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) is expecting an iterable argument, which it will then run through to see if any of its items evaluate to `True`.  Moreover, the expression `True in list` returns a non-iterable boolean value:

```
>>> lst = [False, True, False]
>>> True in lst
True
>>>
```

To fix the problem, you should simply pass the list to `any`:

```
if any(list):
```

You should also refrain from making a user-defined name the same as one of the built-ins.  Doing so overshadows the built-in and makes it unusable in the current scope.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your code is much shorter if written as:

```
if any(file.endswith(suffix, 21, 22) 
       for suffix in ['05', '11', '17', '21', '23']):
```

Answer (score 1):

> any(iterable):
>
> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is
>   empty, return False.

Your code should use:

```
 if any(list):
```